# Authorization in POST method using rest assured

Tags: rest, postman, basic-authentication, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I'm trying to send a POST method to my API and it returns 401 error instead of 200 OK.

Here is the thing:

Using Postman: POST request works fine.

Under Authorization section, I have selected `Basic Auth` and have provided Username/pwd.

Under Headers section, I have given `X-application` and `Content-Type`.
My body in Postman is :

```
{
  "description": "TestAPIPostmannolast",
  "issue_type": {
    "id": "271341877549072389",
    "name": "Design"
  },
  "area": {
    "id": "271341877549072406"
  },
  "issue_id": "9d5ac7da-9626-11e8-9eb6-529269fb1459"
}
```

Using RestAssured: It fails with a 401 error.

```
package basic;

import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class GetRequest {


    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://123.com";

        RestAssured.basePath = "/field-management/api";

        RestAssured.authentication =    RestAssured.basic("username", "password");

    }

    @Test
    public void responseBody(){

        Response response = given()
                .header("X-application", "63fc4887-aed9-497f-bad5-d7ef2b90cdaf")
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body("{\n" +
                        "  \"description\": \"Intellij  \",\n" +
                        "  \"issue_type\": {\n" +
                        "    \"id\": \"271341877549072389\",\n" +
                        "    \"name\": \"Design\"\n" +
                        "  },\n" +
                        "  \"area\": {\n" +
                        "    \"id\": \"271341877549072406\"\n" +
                        "  },\n" +
                        "  \"issue_id\": \"2dd8ae7a-966e-11e8-9eb6-529269fb1459\n" +
                        "\n\"\n" +
                        "}")

                .when()
                .post("/projects/1879048400/areas/271341877549072406/issue/");

        System.out.println(response.body().asString());
    }
```

Response:

```
{"message":"Authentication Failed","errorKey":null}
```

Not sure why is it not working when I try it through RestAssured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below code fixed it. Got this token from Postman

```
 .header("Authorization","Basic cG9sZWFyeTpBdXRoM250MWM=")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below approach:

- Create a Utility method for building the RequestSpecification
- Use the built RequestSpecification Object to make the POST call. You can embed the authentication part in the RequestSpecification.

  ```
  private static RequestSpecification request_spec_builder_POST(Object _body, String _username, String _pass){
      RequestSpecBuilder _builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
      _builder.setBody(_body);

      _builder.setContentType("application/json");
      PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme auth = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
      auth.setUserName(_username);
      auth.setPassword(_pass);
      _builder.setAuth(auth);
      RequestSpecification _spec = _builder.build();
      return RestAssured.given(_spec);
  }
  ```

In your Test Class make use of this to make the POST call like:

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
   RequestSpecification http_req = MyRequestSpecBuilder.request_spec_builder_POST(_obj, username, pass);
   Response _response = http_req.post("/endPoint"); 
}
```